# Не подгружается CSS на Wordpress сайте, net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: php, wordpress

Такая проблема. Один раз в два дня при открытии сайта не подгружаются CSS стили, в консоли выдаёт такую ошибку: failed to load resource A.main.css,qver=5.8... net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Если же обновить сайт, то всё корректно и стили подгружаются.

Обращались в поддержку хостинга, сказали, что это связано с кэшированием, так как со стороны хостинга идут настройки кэширования и на сайте плагин WP Super Cache. Но на сайте плагин удалили, но проблема по-прежнему осталась. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему??

Comment: Решение одно - валить с этого хостинга как можно дальше. Это их проблема, вы с её не решите никак.

Comment: А ответ про кеширование на сайте - в лучшем стиле некомпетентности и отписок.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл такой фигни с кешированием в следующем. У тебя задано кеширование, но данные через какое то время очищаются. Пользователь заходит по старой копии страницы с устаревшим (мёртвым) адресом CSS и получает ошибку. Хотя ошибка ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR вообще не об этом.
А с кеширование я рекомендую:

1. ЛИБО Удалить проблемные файлы из кэш в настройках исключений
2. ЛИБО Задать время жизнь = бесконечность - (для них) и удалять / обновлять кэш им вручную